# Fail2Ban blocks ip despite both ignoreself and ignoreip being set in jail.local

Tags: fail2ban

solution: The IP range in ignoreip was set incorrectly using CIDR.  It should have been 192.168.2.0/24 rather than 192.168.2.1/32.

original post:

[Another user](https://serverfault.com/questions/747379/fail2ban-blocks-ip-in-ignoreip-list) had a similar problem caused by conflicting ignoreip's (jail.local's ignoreip replacing jail.conf's).  However, the only ignoreip I am using is the one in jail.local, and I have not edited jail.conf at all, so the user's solution did not apply for me.

I've made the following changes in jail.local:

**>diff /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local**

> 87c87
> < #ignoreself = true
> ---
> > ignoreself = true
> 92c92
> < #ignoreip = 192.168.2.0/255
> ---
> > ignoreip = 192.168.2.1/32 ::1
> 101c101
> < bantime  = 10m
> ---
> > bantime  = -1
> 208c208
> < banaction = iptables-multiport
> ---
> > banaction = iptables-allports

All of these changes are within the [DEFAULT] block.

I've **>sudo /etc/init.d/fail2ban restart**'ed many times, and **>sudo shutdown -r 0**'d many times as well.  Despite this, every time I try to intentionally fail ssh logins from 192.168.2.13, the IP gets blocked after 5 tries.  After this, I have to manually unban it using **>sudo fail2ban-client set sshd unbanip 192.168.2.13**.

**>tail /var/log/fail2ban.log**

> 2021-08-20 21:43:57,190 fail2ban.jail           [1703]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' started
>
> 2021-08-20 21:44:04,082 fail2ban.filter         [1703]: INFO    [sshd] Found 192.168.2.13 - 2021-08-20 21:44:03
>
> 2021-08-20 21:44:05,792 fail2ban.filter         [1703]: INFO    [sshd] Found 192.168.2.13 - 2021-08-20 21:44:05
>
> 2021-08-20 21:44:10,357 fail2ban.filter         [1703]: INFO    [sshd] Found 192.168.2.13 - 2021-08-20 21:44:09
>
> 2021-08-20 21:44:15,613 fail2ban.filter         [1703]: INFO    [sshd] Found 192.168.2.13 - 2021-08-20 21:44:15
>
> 2021-08-20 21:44:19,166 fail2ban.filter         [1703]: INFO    [sshd] Found 192.168.2.13 - 2021-08-20 21:44:19
>
> 2021-08-20 21:44:19,216 fail2ban.actions        [1703]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 192.168.2.13

Duplicating jail.local (with the appropriate ignoreip, etc.) as jail.conf also did not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring `192.168.2.1/32` would mean you are ignoring that IP alone. But in the logs you've shown you're banning `192.168.2.13`. I think you've made a typo. I think your ignoreip should be

```
ignoreip = 192.168.2.13/32 ::1
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I realized after reading it where the error was: I was using the wrong CIDR prefix.  Like you said, /32 is just a single IP.
192.168.2.0/24 works as intended.
Thanks again!